# jQuery Ajax Json callback issue

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, jquery-callback

Im working on a mobile application, trying to send data from the app to an  API though jQuery Ajax. It keeps giving me a callback error even though i defined my callback.

Code below is the jQuery Ajax connecting to the API

```
function isDashboard(){
   var task = 'balance';
   var json = { // Create object
       "task" : task,
       "merchant" : getSession('x_u'), 
       "token" : getSession('x_token')
   };
   var jsonfull = []; // Push to jsonfull.
   jsonfull.push(json);
   var url = JSON.stringify(json);
   var crypt = CryptoJS.SHA512(getSession('x_token')+task+getSession('x_email')+url).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex);
   $.ajax({
       url: "http://samplesite.com/?p=app&'", 
       crossDomain: true,
       data: {
           json : url,
           hash :crypt
       },
       dataType: "jsonp"
   })
   .done(function (json){ 

       $('#welcome').prepend(json.response);
       alert(json.response);

   })
   .fail(function (jqxhr, textStatus, error){
       var err = textStatus + ", " + error;
       $('#welcome').prepend(err);

   });

}
```

On my receiving file in php, i have

```
$rest = $_GET['json'];
$api = json_decode($rest,true);
$type = "json";
// did some processing with $api
//returning response to the app
$out = [];    
$out['response'] = 'X006';
$out['description'] = 'Invalid hash';
$out['values'] = '';
$out['salt'] = $salt;
$out['hash'] = '';
if($type == 'json'){
    header('Content-Type: text/json');
    $out = $_GET['callback'].'('.json_encode($out).')';
}
echo $out;      
die();
```

i keep getting the error parsererror, Error: jQuery1111036580699938349426_1446328908674 was not called

ill appreciate any help i can get. Regards

Comment: I don't see you echoing out the $out, e.g. `echo $out;` - are you sure you get response?

Comment: @jpaljasma question edited.

Comment: error parser error - is that on the server or client (browser side)? Try to determine on which line the error happens? Do you see request coming in in access_log?

Comment: pls explain, are you trying to say the error is somewhere within the php codes? Kindly simplify your explanation. @jpaljasma

Comment: I am trying to eliminate all possible options. What's left on the table is the answer.

Comment: So which one causes the error? is it JS or PHP?

Comment: @jpaljasma the error was on the server side. It was an encoding issue. Really appreciate your helpful explanation. It now works fine.

Comment: That's awesome @user297056.